# scrapy AttributeError: Response content isn't text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I have setup the following project

```
class DatosRUC_(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "datosRUC"
    start_urls = ['https://www.datosperu.org/']

    def start_requests(self):
        nombre = "datosRUC"
        rucs = [20100050359,
                20536742248
                ]
        for i in rucs:
            print(i)
            req = scrapy.Request(url='https://www.datosperu.org/buscador_empresas.php?buscar='+str(i))
            yield req

def parse(self, response):
    error = 'no_error'
    s = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
    ruc_num = s.find('input', {'id': 'buscar'}).get('value')
    company_link = s.findAll('div',class_="single-product")
    if len(company_link)>0:
        url_company= company_link[0].find('a',href=True)['href']
        url_final = 'https://www.datosperu.org/' + url_empresa
        yield {'ruc':ruc_num,'ruc_link':url_final,'error':error}
    else:
        error = 'no_ruc_found'
        url_final = ''
        yield {'ruc':ruc_num,'ruc_link':url_final,'error':error}
```

However if I send a Request to one of the links I get the following error (ex.):

```
2020-10-15 11:01:08 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://www.datosperu.org/buscador_empresas.php?buscar=20536742248>
...
AttributeError: Response content isn't text
...
```

I'm using a proxy pool, but I don't think that could be the reason, because I have tried other links from another website without any problem.

I have tried to debug it with scrapy-shell but when I send (ex.):

```
fetch(https://www.datosperu.org/buscador_empresas.php?buscar=20536742248)
```

I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

If using `Scrapy` is not a mandatory, you can try `requests` library for get and its fairly simple.

Below is a minor rewrite of your code above using `requests` and it works!.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_request():
    rucs = [20100050359,
            20536742248
            ]
    for i in rucs:
        print(i)
        url = "https://www.datosperu.org/buscador_empresas.php?buscar="+str(i)
        r = requests.get(url)
        resp = parse(r)
        print(resp)

def parse(response):
    error = 'no_error'
    s = BeautifulSoup(response.content,'html.parser')
    ruc_num = s.find('input', {'id': 'buscar'}).get('value')
    company_link = s.findAll('div',class_="single-product")
    if len(company_link)>0:
        url_company= company_link[0].find('a',href=True)['href']
        url_final = 'https://www.datosperu.org/' + url_company
        return {'ruc':ruc_num,'ruc_link':url_final,'error':error}
    else:
        error = 'no_ruc_found'
        url_final = ''
        return {'ruc':ruc_num,'ruc_link':url_final,'error':error}

get_request()
```

Answer (score 0):

use `response.body` - which is bytes
or `response.text` - which is str.
not sure if `response.content` is even existing.